# Integer lattice: find all solutions

Tags: group-theory, integer-lattices

In general, how do you solve the following kind of problems borrowing techniques from Group Theory?

> Describe all points (if any) in the affine integral lattice
>   $$ \mathcal{L} = \{(x, y, z, t) : x + y + z + t = 5 \text{ and } x - z \equiv 0 \mod 12\} \subset \mathbb{Z}^4$$

Comment: I would be inclined to introduce a new unknown $u$ and rewrite the second equation as $x-z+12u=0$. Then you just a system of linear equations over the integers. There are standard methods for solving those, based of Smith Normal Form.

Comment: @DerekHolt I might add that this was a practice question for a group theory exam.

Comment: As you can see from Hagen von Eitzen's answer, the solution is a coset of  subgroup $H < {\mathbb Z}^4$ with $H \cong {\mathbb Z}^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this simple case, we can readily describe $\mathcal L$ as image of a $\Bbb Z^3$: We can pick $x,y\in \Bbb Z$ arbitrarily, then $z=x+12w$ with $w\in \Bbb Z$ and determine $t$ from $x+y+z+t=5$. So
$$\mathcal L=\{\,(x,y,x+12w,5-2x-y-12w)\mid (x,y,w)\in\Bbb Z^3\,\}. $$